# using web services in c# client application

Tags: silverlight, service, web

Im trying to connect to a webservice from silverlight c# application.
I add service reference to the service and now Im trying access it, but Im not able to connect to it like I would expect :

```
WebService1 service = new WebService1();
```

and then I would call:

```
service.SomeMethod();
```

But this is not possible. The added service is a namespace which I cannot instanciate and inside it there is no object to be created as the service.

Can you say me any easy way how to use the web service reference in visual studio or another way to connect to a web service from silverlight application?

thanks

Comment: I think you will need to show a bit more code

Comment: look at these images - notice the Service reference and the intellisense:  http://imageshack.us/f/208/namespace.png/   http://imageshack.us/f/15/namespace2.png/

Comment: It looks like the service is static and does not need to be instantiated - you can just call WebService1.SomeMethod()

Comment: WebService1 is a namespace , therefore cannot be instantiated. Dont know why but it just is. Look at the images I uploaded.